# Copy file from user to inside a jar using Files.copy

Tags: java

So this is what I use to copy image from user to images folder in my project:

```
Files.copy(file.toPath(), Paths.get("/images/"+file.getName()), REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

It works fine from within my project when I build the program but it doesn't work from my jar file. I'm  not even sure if it is possible to copy a file to inside a jar directory.

File structure is like so

```
 -images
    something.jpg
 -stock
    *.java
```

Comment: @JanZyka that is what I thought what is my best bet then? should I move all the files from jar to a separate folder outside?

Comment: That very much depends on your usecase. But yes, generally static resources like images are usually placed in some dedicated folder. Especially when user uploads them. Putting these into jar sounds really odd.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Modify your final JAR? This sounds really weird and not a good idea at all.

Comment: @Tunaki I just want user to be able to add images to the program and there are some already existing images.

Comment: You need to store those images elsewhere, not in your JAR.

Comment: @Tunaki what would be the smartest way to do that? on first execution of code I could create folder images outside of jar and copy files from that jar to that folder? but the problem that code wouldn't work in project it would only work for jar not when I execute it from IDE